# Hide div when img in jQuery prepend load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grafana

in jQuery I have a prepend line which loads an generated image from Grafana.
I have another div which shows "Loading in progress" text because Grafana image take about 3 seconds to generate and load.

Problem is that if i hide that div immediately after prepend line it hide itself immediately.

Is there any solution?

```js
$("#t1_temp_act").click(function() {
    console.log("append");
    $("#grafana-image").remove();
    $("termostat1_grafana").hide();
    $(".termostat1_grafana_loading").show();
    $(".termostat1_grafana").prepend("<img id=\"grafana-image\" src=\"http://192.168.1.113:3000/render/dashboard-solo/db/legadademo?orgId=1&from=now-1d&to=now&panelId=3&width=670&height=350&tz=UTC%2B02%3A00\">Nalaganje v teku...</img>");    
    $(".termostat1_grafana").show();
    sleep(3000);
    $(".termostat1_grafana_loading").hide();    
});
```

```html
<div class="termostat1_grafana_loading" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><b>Nalaganje v teku...</b></div>
<div class="termostat1_grafana" style="width:100%;margin-top: 10px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are essentially "guessing" 3 seconds, this is not very scientific and there's a better way.

Instead, you can replace `.show()` with `.fadeIn()` and use a callback:

```
$(".termostat1_grafana").fadeIn( 10, function() { /* 10 is almost as fast as .show() */
    // animation complete
    $(".termostat1_grafana_loading").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sleep isn't a function in javascript. you need to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".termostat1_grafana_loading").hide();
},3000);
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)